# Replacing String without replacing whole content of file powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to edit this line of a file ("VoIP.Enabled "1"). I wanna change the 1 to a zero. When I change it with

```
$dewprefs = Get-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg

$dewprefs | Select-String "VoIP.Enabled" | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "1","0"} | Set-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg}`
```

However when I use this script, it removes 100 other lines, edits the right line, then deletes everything else, just leaving the line I wanted to edit.

Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-String` acts as a *filter*: that is, the input it is given is only passed out if it *matches a pattern*.

Therefore, *only* the line of interest is written to the output file.

Do not use `Select-String` if *all* input lines - though possibly modified - should be passed through; use *only* `ForEach-Object`, and *conditionally* modify each input line:

```
$dewprefs = Get-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg

$dewprefs |
  ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match 'VoIP\.Enabled') { $_ -replace '1', '0' } else { $_ } } | 
    Set-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg
```

`$_ -match 'VoIP\.Enabled'` now does what `Select-String` did in your original command: it matches only if the input line at hand contains literal `VoIP.Enabled` (note how the `.` is escaped as `\.` to ensure that is treated as a *literal* in the context of a regular expression).

Note how both branches of the `if` statement produce *output*:

- `$_ -replace '1', '0'` outputs the result of replacing all instances of `1` in the input line with `0`
- `$_` simply passes the input line through as-is.

---

Most likely you could replace the `if` statement with a single `-replace` expression, however, and, assuming that the file is small enough to be read as a whole (quite likely, in the case of a configuration file), you can use a variant of [Stu's helpful simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43600630/45375).

Taking full advantage of the fact that `-replace` supports regexes (regular expressions), the code can update lines based on a key name such as `VoIP.Enabled` only, without needing to know that key's *current* value.

```
$key = 'VoIP.Enabled'
$newValue = '1'

# Construct a regex that matches the entire target line.
$regex = '^\s*' + [regex]::Escape($key) + '\b.*$'
# Build the replacement line.
$modifiedLine = "$key $newValue"

(Get-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg) -replace $regex, $modifiedLine | Set-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg
```

Note that writing the output back to the input file only works because the input file was read into memory *as a whole, up front*, due to enclosing the `Get-Content` call in `(...)`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and I see where I'm going wrong, thank you

Answer (score 2):

This will work too, with PowerShell v3+, and is a little more succinct:

```
(Get-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg).replace('"VoIP.Enabled "1"', '"VoIP.Enabled "0"') | 
    Set-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg
```

Your quotes are a little strange (3 double quotes in total?), I've mimicked what you've asked, however.

Comment: This seems a little more of what Im looking for , the quotes hold server config values. Can you maybe help me expand what you written above here. What if I wanted to grab what ever data was between the quotes and edit it, but didnt know what it was, would I a * to point at this data for example.

`Server.Name "Random Server Name"

$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Server Name'`

`(Get-Content.\dewrito_prefs.cfg).replace('"Server.Name"*"','"Server.Name "$name"') | Set-Content .\dewrito_prefs.cfg `

Comment: ++ for a simpler approach; @ETHER: For generic replacements that do no rely on knowing the current value you must use the `-replace` _operator_, which uses _regular expressions_ rather than the `.Replace()` _method_, which works on _literals_ - I've updated my answer to demonstrate.